# Linux cgroup: move a process from one cgroup to another

Tags: linux, permissions, systemd

Preface: I am not 100 percent familiar with systemd and the concepts of unit files, but I have done some reading.

Context: I want to move a process from one cgroup tree to another, on distro running systemd and (non-systemd lets say upstart). More specifically lets say the cgroup tree looks like this.

Basically hierarchy looks like this relative to my_root

```
                     my_root
                        |
                  ______ ___________
                  |                |
                  d11             d12
              (P lives here)       |
                              ___________
                              |          |
                             d21        d22
```

then P moves under d21 or

```
                     my_root
                        |
                  ______ ___________
                  |                |
                  d11             d12
                                   |
                              ___________
                              |          |
                             d21        d22
                     (P lives here now)
```

For sake of completeness lets say 
`my_root = /sys/fs/cgroups/cpu,cpuacct/my_root`

Lets talk about non-systemd bucket: If I am running on a distro that is not running systemd I can just echo the pid of `P1` into `cgroups.procs` of `d21` and then it will move my process to that cgroup.

And now the `systemd` use case, and this is what I am unsure of lets say I do the same thing that I did above, there are two things that may happen.

- The process moves there and stays there.
- The process moves there initially, but after sometime it either goes back or goes to root cgroup for that particular controller.

I want to avoid the latter.
Basically I am thinking that when I am specifying the unit file for my application I want to take ownership of cgroup that the application is launched in, for example the application takes ownership of `my_root` cgroup, so that systemd does not interfere with the process move.

Now to the multipart question.

- Will systemd really move away the process from the cgroup that I had moved it in?
- If yes then what do I need to do to take ownership of the cgroup in the unit file. I am looking for some specific examples of unit files.

resource : https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/